# Mysql: How to retrieve datetime which created within 9hour59mins30s from now?

Tags: mysql, sql

Originally I have MySQL query as below:

```
SELECT sub.id, sub.content, sub.time, date_format(sub.time, '%d %b %Y')
FROM (SELECT * from accounts) AS sub 
ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 3
```

Now I have to add another condition, that is, the retrived account must be created within 9hour59mins30s from now.

So I tweaked with many tries but failed, such as:

```
SELECT sub.id, sub.content, sub.time(curdate(), interval 9 hour 59 min 30 sec), 
     date_format(sub.time, '%d %b %Y') 
FROM (SELECT * from accounts) AS sub 
ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 3
```

How could I add the new condition into my original SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I fully understand the logic.  The following gets all accounts created in the past 9 hours 30 minutes and 30 seconds:

```
select sub.id, sub.content, sub.time, date_format(sub.time, '%d %b %Y')
from accounts sub
where sub.time >= date_sub(now(), interval 30 + 59*60 + 9*60*60 second)
order by time ASC
limit 3;
```

In most of the world, `10 hour` would be a fine approximation.

Comment: Good work, Gordon.  You should explain to the gentleman how you reached the magic number, 30 + 59*60 + 30*60*60, so he FULLY understands your solution.  Intriguingly, my solution incorporates a rather different magic number.

Comment: @BruceDavidWilner . . . LOL.  There was a typo in that formula.

Comment: Thanks guys, saw your comment while trying to figure out the magic number. Problem solved, this is my last bellyache of my three-month commitment. Cheers.